# php curl proxy request blocked

Tags: php, curl, proxy

i want to get web page of this url `"http://namnak.com"` in my server but this url blocked curl request from my server this is my code :

```
<?php
$proxy = "138.68.173.29 :8080";
$proxy = explode(':', $proxy);
$url = "http://namnak.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$exec = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_error($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo $exec;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the type of proxy you want to use, for example, SOCKS5:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 
5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURL_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

Start by trying that and we'll figure it out from there!

EDIT: In some cases, SOCKS5 isn't defined in curl, you can use its value which is equal to 7